# How do I force ActiveRecord to reload a class?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, migration

I'm creating a bunch of migrations, some of which are standard "create table" or "modify table" migrations, and some of which modify data.  I'm using my actual ActiveRecord models to modify the data, a la:

```
Blog.all.each do |blog|
  update_some_blog_attributes_to_match_new_schema
end
```

The problem is that if I load the Blog class, then modify the table, then use the Blog class again, the models have the old table definitions, and cannot save to the new table.  Is there a way to reload the classes and their attribute definitions so I can reuse them?

Answer (score 143, accepted):

The answer is yes!

```
Blog.reset_column_information
```

Comment: Watch out for models with relationships. If `class Blog; belongs_to Owner; end`, then you may need to `Owner.reset_column_information` in addition to Blog.

Comment: Reset all the columns!

`ActiveRecord::Base.descendants.each{|c| c.reset_column_information}`

Comment: Throw `Rails.application.eager_load!` in front of any calls to descendants to fix issues with non-autoloaded models

Comment: I wonder why this is not triggered automatically after every schema update, since migrations are not very time-critical.

Answer (score 5):

I always used new models in migrations

```
    MyBlog < ActiveRecord::Base
      set_table_name 'blogs'
    end

    def self.up
      MyBlog.all.each do |blog|
        update_some_blog_attributes_to_match_new_schema
      end
    end
```

But `Blog.reset_column_information` is more convenient.

Answer (score 3):

Create new instances:

---

```
Old_blogs = Blog.all
```

> # change/modify db table in here

```
New_blogs = Blog.all # this should be reloaded or you could use the .reload on this
```

> # change information, load old into new

## ex.

```
Old_blogs.each do |blog|
  New_blogs.find(blog.id).title = blog.title
end
```